# One word for spending money less than the amount that someone/something requires

Tags: word-choice, word-request, verbs

What word should be used for the habit of spending money less than the amount that someone/something requires?

For example, how to say:

> Don't spend too little on your child's education?

Comment: "Don't *skimp* on your child's education." By the way, we say "spending too little money"--*less* is a comparative form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into these words:

1. stingy
2. cheap
3. miserly
4. tightfisted

Depending on some other context, you might also want to look at

1. frugal
2. scrimp

---

I forgot to include skimp! That one was the first one on my mind.
As StoneyB writes, we would say

> Don't skimp on your child's education.

I gave a list because I was thinking of other ways to say this.
Like "Don't be stingy when it comes to your kids education."

Answer (score 1):

Not a verb but you can use the adjective [*parsimonious*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parsimonious&t=crmtb01).

As in; "*Do not be too parsimonious with your child's education*".

The word describes someone who is unwilling to spend money.